# Android Worker does not extract value from inputData for some reason

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV4iZ.png) of my debug view. It is clearly visible in variables view that `intupData` contains value for the key that corresponds `KEY_ISSUE_ID` (`issue.id`) but

```
inputData.getString(KEY_ISSUE_ID)
```

results in `null`. Even more strange is that in other `Workers` very same code works well.
Is there any caveat that might lead to such behavior?

BTW. What differs this worker is that it is chained after bunch of other workers with `ArrayCreatingInputMerger`. According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work#input-mergershttps://) it should receive an output of these workers as an input. But it does not look like it receives these data.

> the output of parent OneTimeWorkRequests are passed in as inputs to the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`ArrayCreatingInputMerger` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ArrayCreatingInputMerger.html):

> - If this is the first time we encountered the key:
>
>   - If it's an array, put it in the output
>   - **If it's a primitive, turn it into a size 1 array and put it in the output**

So your `inputData` has an array of strings of size 1, not a String.

Therefore you'd want to use [`getStringArray()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data#getStringArray(java.lang.String)) and get the first element of that array (if you only care about the first element):

```
val issueId = inputData.getStringArray(KEY_ISSUE_ID).firstOrNull()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. "ArrayCreatingInputMerger attempts to merge the inputs, creating arrays when necessary." from here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work#input-mergers confused me.

Comment: Yeah, I think the 'when necessary' is more about the logic when you already have an array (where it doesn't need to create a new array, it just uses the existing array) rather than the logic where you have a non-array type (which are always transformed into an array). You might consider [filing a documentation bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697) as I agree that this could definitely be more clear in the documentation.

Comment: Sure. Will do this.

Comment: Right, the merging always happens. The creation of brand new arrays is what only sometimes happens.